# How to disable borders and underlininng of Entry on WIndows .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, windows, maui

I am trying to customize an Entry in MAUI. The main aim is to disable borders and underlining. This is my current code in MauiProgram.cs file:

```
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(MdeEntry), (handler, view) =>
        {
#if ANDROID
            handler.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
#elif WINDOWS
            //handler.PlatformView.Background = Colors.Transparent.ToPlatform();
            //handler.PlatformView.BorderThickness = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Thickness(0);
            //handler.PlatformView.GotFocus += (s, e) =>
            //{
            //    handler.PlatformView.Background = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Microsoft.UI.Colors.Transparent);
            //    handler.PlatformView.BorderThickness = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Thickness(0);
            //    handler.PlatformView.BorderBrush = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Microsoft.UI.Colors.Red);
            //};
#endif
        });
```

As you see, commented code - is my attemts to solve my issue and all of this code for Windows is not working. But, this one for Android is working as I want:

```
#if ANDROID
            handler.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
```

Does someone know how to disable borders and underlining of Entry on Windows?

Comment: (1) “not working” - what happens? (2) Are you testing on Windows 11? Maui Windows is built on Windows App SDK (not UWP), and its best to test with Windows 11 rather than 10.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yes, I am testing it on WIndows 11. Not working - means borders and underlining are not disabled and on Windws I still see them in Entry. I found the way how to disable borders and underlining while Entry is not Focused.
[ handler.PlatformView.BorderThickness = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Thickness(0); ]
But when I click on the Entry the borders and underlining appears....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add this on the App.XAML in package Platforms/Windows

```xml
    <maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
        <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThickness">0</Thickness>
        <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThicknessFocused">0</Thickness>
    </maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your Answer is Crisp Clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**First Create a Class with BorderlessEntry and add the below code**

```cs
      public class BorderlessEntry: Entry
      {
      }
```

**Next in the MauiProgram.cs file add the below line of code**

```
            public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
            {
                var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
                builder
                    .UseMauiApp<App>()
                    .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                    {
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                    });
    
                Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("Borderless",(handler,view) =>
                {
                    if(view is BorderlessEntry)
                    {
    #if ANDROID
                   handler.PlatformView.Background=null;
                   handler.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
    #elif IOS || MACCATALYST
                        handler.PlatformView.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.Clear;
                        handler.PlatformView.Layer.BorderWidth= 0;
                        handler.PlatformView.BorderStyle = UIKit.UITextBorderStyle.None;
    #elif WINDOWS
                         handler.PlatformView.BorderThickness= new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Thickness(0);
    #endif
                    }
    
                });
                return builder.Build();
            }
```

**final in Solution Explore open Platforms/Windows/App. Xaml and add the below line of code**

```cs
     <maui: MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
         <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThickness">0</Thickness>
         <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThicknessFocused">0</Thickness> 
     </Maui: MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
```

<controls:BorderlessEntry Placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" />

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**